# Can I create a Python extension module in D (instead of C)

Tags: python, module, d

I hear D is link-compatible with C. I'd like to use D to create an extension module for Python. Am I overlooking some reason why it's never going to work?

Comment: Yes, this is possible because D is capable of interfacing with C and Python is also capable of interfacing with C (either through it's C/C++ API or ctypes)

It's just an issue of making your D code have the extern "C" modifiers, and then making use of the python C/C++ API or ctypes to access them. It looks like wuub's link contains modules for both D and Python that will make the entire process easier.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wait? Something like this  http://www.dsource.org/projects/pyd (previously http://pyd.dsource.org/)

Comment: Yep PyD is what you want.  Anyone know if it works with the latest DMD 1.x or 2.x versions?

Comment: The commit messages show that it was intended to work with both at times. I doubt it works with latest D2 as that has changed a lot but don't expect it to work too well with D1 either as the last change to /trunk was august 07 http://dsource.org/projects/pyd/log/trunk

Answer (score 2):

Sounds easy and people here who say it's just up to the  C API don't know how difficult it is to integrate the Boehm GC used by D within Python. PyD looks like a typical concept proof where people haven't realized the real world problems.

Comment: I am failing to see how this answers the question... Also, where did you find the information that D uses Boehm's GC? :)